# Find <head> tag on Wordpress 6.0 Twenty Twenty-Two Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

When I tried to add code on  on Twenty Twenty-Two theme I could not find header.php as it not uses like this pattern. Please tell me where to find the file and if the file is absent where to find the  tag to add something inside the tag.

[Twenty_Twenty_Two Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WagiV.png)

Answer (score 3):

In the WordPress [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/templates-and-template-parts/#block-markup) for block themes like Twenty Twenty-Two, `<head>` is added automatically. Adding code, for example, Google Analytics, is recommended through a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/).

or [wp_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/#user-contributed-notes) hook, added to function.php preferably child theme:

```
function hook_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>
            alert('Page is loading...');
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_javascript');
```

Comment: Yes I read that, but what will happen if I want to add my custom code on head, is there any hook to do that. wp_head() is not working. I will check the plugin also. But what if I dont want to use plugin.

Comment: Without the plugin, the wp_head hook worked for me. I have edited my answer.